# Every recommended job is looking for applicants with senior level experience

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Unfortunately, I don't have that kind of experience. In fact, I don't even have mid-level experience. I've only worked for a year, and I'm still studying. I'd like to see jobs that are more aligned with my experience level so that, when I apply, I can actually hope to expect a response. Can I tune my recommendations somehow to fit this? If not, can this be made possible in the future?

Furthermore, I haven't seen a single recommended job offering internships. As mentioned earlier, I'm still a student, so I'd be more inclined to apply for an internship than a full time role. Is SO Jobs currently linked with any companies that offer internships?

Comment: 38,513 REPUTATION and  looking for internship.. Wowwww

Comment: Reputation tells how much time you spend on Stack Overflow. In real life it doesn't count as work experience, even though we all wish it would.

Comment: @JJJ I am glad my rep does not reflect my work experience. I could not have done all I did with 701 work experience ;)    >20,000 lines Python, >38,000 lines GTK user interface code, 3 open source applications

Comment: @theGtknerd, you think experience is measured by number of lines of code you write. LOL :)

Comment: Also sometimes its funny and sad when I see job description with certain technology with X years of experience but that specific technology itself was not even released in market X years back.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can update your experience level under Job Preferences to improve recommendations.

You can find [internship jobs here](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/internship-developer-jobs). Here are quick links to [student](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/student-developer-jobs) and [junior](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/junior-developer-jobs) jobs as well. If you'd like to receive a weekly email with new jobs that match your exact query, click 'create alert' from those pages.

Comment: I wonder why it assumes by default that everyone is a senior

Comment: I would expect the norm to be quite the opposite.

Comment: @Magisch I think by default it simply doesnt filter either way by default.